# php -> sql missing leading zero

Tags: php, sql

I am passing ID´s, with a query to a SQL database. The ID is generated by `new DateTime()`, which I format afterwards. The whole workflow works, SQL database connection is established and the ID´s are added.

The problem is the leading zero´s, for example todays date 08.10.2021. Those is shown as 08102021.. in PHP but added as 8102021.. in sql.The leading zero is gone. I already played around with different column types in sql, like `nchar`, `varchar`, `int` etc. each time the same problem.

**What do I miss?**

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date = $date->format("dmYHisu");

    $addQuery = "INSERT INTO nodes (id) VALUES ($date)";
 
    if (sqlsrv_query($connection, $addQuery)) {
        echo "Node added.";
    } else {
        die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

I also hardcoded the passed value, each time the same problem.

Comment: _"What do I miss?"_ - the text literal delimiters inside your query, to let the database know that this is supposed to be a string value, and not a number ...

Comment: @ICoded, always use parameterized statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. More information about passing and retrieving `datetime` values using PHP Driver for SQL Server can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leading zero mean it's string so you have to put single quote to your `$date` variable like this

```
$addQuery = "INSERT INTO nodes (id) VALUES ('".$date."')";
```

Comment: Thanks @adam, completely missed that.

Comment: The proper fix is `$addQuery = "INSERT INTO nodes (id) VALUES (?)";` and then prepare and bind.