# sqlsrv_query returns no rows, no errors for a long query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have an unusually long query (13sec+ for our system) that returns no results while using sqlsrv_query, but gives me 331 rows when I enter directly the SQL query on the server. sqlsrv_num_rows returns 0 and sqlsrv_errors is empty.

```
<?php
$connInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('SQL2008', $connInfo);

if ($conn)
    {
    $sql_q = "SELECT TblOrder.FldJobNb, TblOrder.FldOrdCre As DateReception, TblOrder.FldReclamerDate As DateDebutPORev, TblOrder.FldPOReviewApprovedDate As DateFinPORev,
                        TblOrder.FldPrinted, capsule_order.temps_reception_planification As DateReceptionPLANIF, TblOrder.FldPriced,
                        CASE
                            WHEN ISNULL(TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate, 0) = 0
                            THEN capsule_order.temps_reception_planification
                            ELSE TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate
                        END As TempsFinRevue,
                        (SELECT TOP 1 TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldDate FROM [TCS].[dbo].[TblOrderXFeredNotifications] WHERE TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldOrdID = TblOrder.FldOrdID ORDER BY TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldNoLigne) As DatePlanification,
                        TblOrder.FldXfer2Sched, TblOrder.FldOrdMod As DateDernierMod, TblOrder.FldOrdStatusDate As DateDernierStatut, TblOrder.FldOrdReq As DateBesoin
                FROM [TCS].[dbo].[TblOrder] RIGHT JOIN [TCS].[dbo].[capsule_order] ON TblOrder.FldJobNB = capsule_order.FldJobNB
                WHERE '" . $dateDebut->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.').'000' . "' <= TblOrder.FldOrdCre AND TblOrder.FldOrdCre <= '" . $dateFin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.').'000' . "'";
// die($sql_q);  Query that I enter into SQL Server and gives me 331 results after 13secs
    $query= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_q, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

    if ($query)
        {
        if (sqlsrv_num_rows($query) > 0)
            {
            while ($result= sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
                {
                // ...
                }
            }
        else
            { die(var_dump(sqlsrv_num_rows($query))); }
        }
    else
        { die("query".$sql_q.'<br>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
    }
else
    { die ("Connection défectueuse."); } ?>
```

Thank you a lot for your support,

Renaud

Comment: Learn to write TSQL using best practices. Give your tables aliases and use them for every column reference. Beware the problems of using 3-part names - your connection should generally determine which database to use for your object references. Your RIGHT JOIN is defeated by your reference to columns in TblOrder - converting it into an inner join.

Comment: Simplify your life (and perhaps avoid logic problems). Your CASE expression can be rewritten as `ISNULL(TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate, TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate)` with some assumptions about what you actually store in the first column.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (missing rows) with a much simpler query with no parameters and no concatenation. I do not think the issue here is the complexity or "poor TSQL" of the query--it produces results on the server, and it sounds like it's producing the results he expects. The problem is that `sqlsrv_query` isn't returning the expected result. In my case, I can identify specific rows that are returned when I run the query with the Visual Studio Code SQL Server extension that `sqlsrv_query` does nto return.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following:

- Pass `datetime` values to SQL Server using unambiguous `datetime` format (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.zzz`) (my experience is summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218)).
- Don't concatenate strings to generate a statement. Always use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- If you want to check if the result set from your current statement has one or more rows, you may use `sqlsrv_has_rows()` instead of `sqlsrv_num_rows()` and use a default (`forward`) cursor.

The following example, based on your code, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
$connInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('SQL2008', $connInfo);

if ($conn)
    {
    $sql_q = "
        SELECT 
            TblOrder.FldJobNb, 
            TblOrder.FldOrdCre As DateReception, 
            TblOrder.FldReclamerDate As DateDebutPORev, 
            TblOrder.FldPOReviewApprovedDate As DateFinPORev,
            TblOrder.FldPrinted, capsule_order.temps_reception_planification As DateReceptionPLANIF, TblOrder.FldPriced,
            CASE
                WHEN ISNULL(TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate, 0) = 0 THEN capsule_order.temps_reception_planification
                ELSE TblOrder.FldContractReviewCompletedDate
            END As TempsFinRevue,
            (
            SELECT TOP 1 TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldDate 
            FROM [TCS].[dbo].[TblOrderXFeredNotifications] 
            WHERE TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldOrdID = TblOrder.FldOrdID 
            ORDER BY TblOrderXFeredNotifications.FldNoLigne
            ) As DatePlanification,
            TblOrder.FldXfer2Sched, 
            TblOrder.FldOrdMod As DateDernierMod, 
            TblOrder.FldOrdStatusDate As DateDernierStatut, 
            TblOrder.FldOrdReq As DateBesoin
        FROM [TCS].[dbo].[TblOrder] 
        RIGHT JOIN [TCS].[dbo].[capsule_order] ON TblOrder.FldJobNB = capsule_order.FldJobNB
        WHERE ? <= TblOrder.FldOrdCre AND TblOrder.FldOrdCre <= ?
    ";
    $query = sqlsrv_query(
        $conn, 
        $sql_q, 
        array($dateDebut->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s').'.000', $dateFin->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s').'.000')
    );
    if ($query)
        {
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($query))
            {
            while ($result= sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
                {
                // ...
                }
            }
        else
            { die(var_dump(sqlsrv_num_rows($query))); }
        }
    else
        { die("query".$sql_q.'<br>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
    }
else
    { die ("Connection défectueuse."); } 
?>
```