# Return value of from a sqlsrv query using a stored procedure

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm having issues on managing to get the value of a result of a query. It returns the number of rows (1) of the result but not the value of that row, this is my php code:

```php
if(isset($_POST['procesar'])){
      $fechaDesde = $_POST['fechaDesde'];
      $fechaHasta = $_POST['fechaHasta'];
      //$query ="SELECT SUM(precioProducto) from ventas where fecha_de_venta BETWEEN '$fechaDesde' and '$fechaHasta'";
      $query ="{call [dbo].[mostrar_total_ventas] (?,?)}";
      $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query, $params);
      $resultados = sqlsrv_query($con, $query, $params);
      echo('<br />');
    
    if ($resultado !== NULL){
      $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($resultado);
      if ($rows = true){
          print_r($rows);
      }
    }
    }
```

and this is my stored procedure:

```
    alter proc mostrar_total_ventas
    @fechaDesde datetime,
    @fechaHasta datetime
    as
    SELECT SUM(precioProducto) as Ventas from ventas
    where fecha_de_venta BETWEEN @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta
```

I'd like my php code to show the result of the stored procedure

Edit: I added these lines to my code, and the result of both var_dumps is NULL:

````php
    if(sqlsrv_has_rows($resultado)){
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado,)){
    var_dump($row[0]);
    var_dump($row['Ventas']);
  }
}```
````

Comment: So you do not have the SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC parameter ?

Comment: No, I didn't have it, but I added it and didn't make any difference.

Comment: put your stored procedure as a normal query string in your PHP and re-try (or do you have special reason to use stored procedure ?)

Comment: Yes, I tried that too (hence the commented variable), made no difference thought. I was using it that way because I used that procedure for a win app form too.

Comment: @Carlos, you need to define the `$params` variable, In your case `$params = array($fechaDesde, $fechaHasta);`. If you pass datetime values as text, you need to use unambiguous datetime format. My experience is summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218).