# Laravel timestamp The value is outside the valid range when converting an NVARCHAR data type to a datetime data type

Tags: php, sql-server, timestamp, laravel-10

Good morning!
I am working on a project using Laravel 10 and SQL database, until Friday I could insert, update, and seed the database without any problem. Today (Monday), the database is complaining about every timestamp.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server] The value is outside the valid range when converting an
> NVARCHAR data type to a datetime data type.
>
> (Connection: morebase, SQL: insert into [roles] ([name], [updated_at],
> [created_at]) values (admin, 2023-11-13 09:23:01, 2023-11-13
> 09:23:01))

I don't remember changing something to cause this!

I have created a ModelBase extending Model and tried to change the date format, and every other model extend from this new model, ex:

```
/**
 * The default datetime format.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

but no look!

Does somebody have a light for me?

Thank you!

Comment: I ususally use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` as datetime format. My own experience is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218).

Comment: It worked, can you please explain that a little? I don't understand it.
 (And many thanks)

Comment: Using the `T` separator between the date portion and the time portion makes it an unambiguous format so that it doesn't explode on SQL Servers with `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` in effect, e.g.: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PKevqGtd)